# Custom Operator States (queued, success, etc.) in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow

In Apache Airflow (2.x), each Operator Instance has a state as defined [here (airflow source repo)](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e351eada1189ed50abef8facb1036599ae96399d/airflow/utils/state.py).

I have two use cases that don't seem to clearly fall into the pre-defined states:

1. Warn, but don't fail - This seems like it should be a very standard use case and I am surprised to not see it in the out-of-the-box airflow source code. Basically, I'd like to color-code a node with something eye-catching - say orange - corresponding to a non-fatal warning, but continue execution as normal otherwise. Obviously you can print warnings to the log, but finding them takes more work than just looking at the colorful circles on the DAGs page.
2. "Sensor N/A" or "Data not ready" - This would be a status that gets assigned when a sensor notices that data in the source system is not yet ready, and that downstream operators can be skipped until the next execution of the DAG, but that nothing in the data pipeline is broken. Basically an expected end-of-branch.

Is there a good way of achieving either of these use cases with the out-of-the-box Airflow node states? If not, is there a way to defining custom operator states? Since I am running airflow on a managed service (MWAA), I don't think changing the source code of our deployment is an option.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The task states are tightly integrated with Airflow. There's no way to configure which logging levels lead to which state. I'd say the easiest way is to grep log files for "WARNING" or set up a log aggregation service e.g. Elasticsearch to make log files searchable.

For #2, sensors have no knowledge about *why* a sensor timed out. After `timeout` or `execution_timeout` is reached, they simply raise an Exception. You can deal with exceptions using [trigger_rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules), but these still don't take the reason for an exception into account.

If you want more control over this, I would implement your own Sensor which takes an argument e.g. `data_not_ready_timeout` (which is smaller than `timeout` and `execution_timeout`). In the `poke()` method, check if `data_not_ready_timeout` has been reached, and raise an AirflowSkipException if so. This will skip downstream tasks. Once `timeout` or `execution_timeout` are reached, the task is failed. Look at `BaseSensorOperator.execute()` for some inspiration to get the initial starting date of a sensor.

Comment: >  In the poke() method, check if data_not_ready_timeout has been reached, and raise an AirflowSkipException if so. This will skip downstream tasks.

I do believe this works for my use case. Thanks,